# How to see if a FreeRTOS task has been deleted

Tags: c, embedded, task, microcontroller, freertos

*Note: this is a horrible design pattern, and ephemeral FreeRTOS tasks should not be created.* I acknowledge this in my attempt at writing a [FreeRTOS best practices guide, bullet #17 here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/NOTES_architecture_and_best_practices.md#for-freertos-also-applies-to-many-bare-metal-or-other-robotics-systems):

> [SAFETY-CRITICAL] Use software timers and callbacks, not short-lived (temporary) tasks that just time out, do something, and delete themselves.

...but I'm stuck in a legacy code base and fixing things one-at-a-time, so for now...

---

What's the best way (perhaps even better: what are various valid ways) to see if a FreeRTOS task has been deleted? Currently, I'm tracking its handle and setting it to `NULL` before calling `vTaskDelete()` on it, like this. Notice I'm calling `myTaskHandle = NULL;` before `vTaskDelete(NULL);`:

```c
static TaskHandle_t myTaskHandle = NULL;

void myTask(void* params)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        // do stuff
        // - the code may exit this for loop to be killed under
        //   certain conditions
    }

    // Manually force the handle to NULL to track when I've deleted it!
    myTaskHandle = NULL;
    vTaskDelete(NULL); // Delete self
}

// This function can be called multiple times, so it must ensure it doesn't
// try to create the same task again until it's been previously deleted.
void myTaskInit()
{
    // Here I check if the task is already running, and don't spawn it again
    // if it is.
    if (myTaskHandle != NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: myTask task already running");
        return;
    }

    static StackType_t taskStack[configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE];
    static StaticTask_t taskControlBlock;
    myTaskHandle = xTaskCreateStatic(
        myTask, 
        "My Task", 
        configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, 
        NULL,
        tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1,
        taskStack, 
        &taskControlBlock);
}
```

Is there a better way to see if the task is deleted or not? Currently I'm doing the `if (myTaskHandle != NULL)` check.

There's a little bit of a race condition here, too:

```c
    myTaskHandle = NULL;
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
```

It's *possible* that `myTask` gets preempted by another task right after `myTask` calls `myTaskHandle = NULL;` but before it calls `vTaskDelete(NULL)`. If this happens, and the other task calls `myTaskInit()` before `myTask` gets a chance to call `vTaskDelete(NULL)`, then `myTaskInit()` will think that `myTask` is already deleted (since its handle is `NULL`) and recreate the task *on top of an already-existing task which is about to be deleted!* This will result in undefined behavior.

So, part of me thinks I need these guards:

```c
    taskENTER_CRITICAL();  // disable FreeRTOS context switches
    myTaskHandle = NULL;
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
    taskEXIT_CRITICAL();   // re-enable FreeRTOS context switches
```

...but I don't think that will work, because the `taskEXIT_CRITICAL();` line will never be reached after `vTaskDelete(NULL);` is called, right? Or am I wrong?

Update: it appears I am right. The task yields at the end of the `vTaskDelete()` function prior to exiting. See here, where it calls `portYIELD_WITHIN_API()`, which yields and does a task context switch at that point I believe: https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/0240cd55f/tasks.c#L2297-L2311:

```c
            /* Force a reschedule if it is the currently running task that has just
             * been deleted. */
            if( xSchedulerRunning != pdFALSE )
            {
                if( pxTCB == pxCurrentTCB )
                {
                    configASSERT( uxSchedulerSuspended == 0 );
                    portYIELD_WITHIN_API(); // <===== HERE =====
                }
                else
                {
                    mtCOVERAGE_TEST_MARKER();
                }
            }
```

Note also that I don't think [`eTaskGetState()`](https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#eTaskGetState) can tell me if the task is deleted. One of the valid states is indeed `Deleted`, but I *think* that means it is simply waiting for the idle task to clean it up, and once it does, it will no longer have a state at all.

> ```
> State     Returned Value
> ...  
> Deleted   eDeleted (the tasks TCB is waiting to be cleaned up)
> ```

### References

1. https://www.freertos.org/xTaskCreateStatic.html

Note: I put this question [on the FreeRTOS forum too](https://forums.freertos.org/t/how-to-see-if-a-freertos-task-has-been-deleted/18969), just in case.

Comment: Richard Barry, FreeRTOS founder, [replied (somewhat vaguely) here](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/April_2013/freertos_Checking_for_and_deleting_task_handle_7936845.html). That might be my answer: `The vTaskDelete function can’t do it as the parameter is not passed in by reference, but the task that calls the delete function can null the handle if that’s what is required.` (This is also a very old response from 2013, though, and may be obsolete.)

Comment: For actual safety-critical applications, a cyclic timer driven by a hardware interrupt is the common way to deal with actual safety-related tasks, like supervising safety components etc. I'm not sure if that's your use case here though?

Comment: @Lundin, `a cyclic timer driven by a hardware interrupt`...sounds like you're describing the FreeRTOS scheduler. It runs on a dedicated timer/counter interrupt.

Comment: Yep that too would be implemented as such. I'd leave critical tasks to a life of their own outside the RTOS though, so in case everything goes wrong, that part is still running. But then I probably wouldn't use open source for anything requiring some form of reliability guarantee either.

Comment: @Lundin, I'm actually surprised that you wouldn't use FreeRTOS in a safety-critical design. It's been around for decades with an excellent track record and reliability and (I think) is used in tens of thousands of different safety-critical products around the world. Anyway, I've been using it for years, and when used appropriately (_not_ per the nutty legacy design pattern I'm working in above), it works very well. FreeRTOS is a safety-critical, hard-real-time, priority-based pre-emptive light-weight memory-constrained operating system for microcontrollers.

Comment: It is a bit "spammy" drawing traffic to your own project. The statement of your own rule adds nothing other than your opinion either, and not directly relevant.  With respect to safety critical, if FreeRTOS was suitable for safety critical, the derived work SafeRTOS would not exist.  It is certified to various safety standards for industrial, medical, automotive, and aerospace industries.  You cannot claim safety critical compliance unless your product has been certified.  Using pre certified libraries makes that little easier, you only then have to worry about your own code being compliant.

Comment: @Clifford, [here's my motiviation](https://forums.freertos.org/t/how-to-see-if-a-freertos-task-has-been-deleted/18969/2?u=ercaguy) for why I added that preface to the start of the answer. I don't want people focused on the bad architectural design of what I'm doing when I already know it's a bad architectural design, and: I don't want passers-by over the years to follow the design in my question on new work when it's a lousy architectural design in the first place. I'm saying: "hey, I know this is bad, but for reasons, I'm doing it anyway, now how do I do my bad design _bug-free_?"

Comment: Understood, but you rather laboured the point rendering it a bit TL;DR.  I am now more concerned that you think FreeRTOS is safety-critical., so you avoided one distraction but triggered another!

Comment: @GabrielStaples There are som big problems with open source: it is constantly modified, it has no usefulness/quality goals and nobody is responsible for anything. Look at gcc, it's been around forever and the current versions >13.0 are by far the buggiest I've ever seen. There is no testing, no goal, just random people doing random modifications nobody asked for and thereby breaking things. Back in the days you'd encounter a gcc bug per year at most, now it is one or several per week. There is just no way you can use the latest gcc in a professional setting.

Comment: As for safety-critical applications, the toughest safety levels usually require full validation of any OS used and that limits your options severely. Better to keep things as simple as possible, decentralize tasks over several MCUs and keep them bare metal.